# Laravel change default primary key of users table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to change the default primary key from `id` of `users` table to `userId`, but Laravel authentication mechanism always checks for `id` from `users` table. Example:

> Users::check() and Users::attempt()

These functions always check for `id` attribute of `users` table, how to change this behavior of Laravel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To override the primary key used to search you must define the primaryKey property on the User model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'userId';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`protected $primaryKey = 'Your_Primary_key';`

In the Models.

> Probably worth pointing that if the primaryKey you define is not an an integer key, you also need to add these:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Otherwise the key will be casted to int

Answer (score 1):

> Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the
>   `id` (or the custom `$primaryKey`)

So, in your `User` model use

```
protected $primaryKey = 'userId';
```