# Auth::login not logging on newly created user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to allow users to log in to my website using Twitch's OAuth flow. The whole fetching of an access token and subsequently user data works, but I also want to store some user data in my database so I can assign roles to certain people. After successfully fetching user data, I've got the following code in `HomeController`

```
public function redirect(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // fetch data

    $this->authService->authenticateUser($response, $this->userRepository);

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

`authenticateUser()`

```
public function authenticateUser(array $response, UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository): void
{
    $data = $response['content']->data[0];

    $user = $userRepository->findByTwitchId($data->id);

    if (!$user) {
        $user = $userRepository->create($data);
    }

    Auth::login($user);
}
```

The two repository functions are quite simple as well;

`findByTwitchId()`

```
public function findByTwitchId(string $twitchId): ?User
{
    return User::where('twitch_id', $twitchId)->first();
}
```

`create()`

```
public function create($data): User
{
    return User::create([
        'twitch_id' => $data->id,
        'login_name' => $data->login,
        'display_name' => $data->display_name,
        'email' => $data->email,
        'profile_image' => $data->profile_image_url
    ]);
}
```

`User` model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $primaryKey = 'twitch_id';
}
```

Everything up till `Auth::login($user)` in `authenticateUser` works. If a user already exists, that user is returned, otherwise a new user is created and that one is returned.

However, I can't seem to get `Auth::login($user)` to work with a newly created user. Only when a user goes through the login flow a second time (so when a user has already been saved to the database) does logging in work. To make things weirder, when I add `dd(Auth::check())` below `Auth::login()` it returns true, but when I subsequently do that same check in `HomeController@index` (where the user is redirected to after logging in), it returns false.

I'm quite honestly lost on why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

print your $user in both cases for new and exist. lets check if something is missing in new user before Auth::login($user) function.

```
public function authenticateUser(array $response, UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository): void
    {
        $data = $response['content']->data[0];

        $user = $userRepository->findByTwitchId($data->id);

        if (!$user) {
            $user = $userRepository->create($data);
        }


        Auth::login($user);
    }
```

Comment: Could have something to do with the primary key I've set in my `User` model? I've set it to `twitch_id` as that's the relevant id for my website, not the database id. When I dump a newly created user, the normal id field isn't returned, when I dump an already existing one it is returned. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed something I missed before. When dumping a newly created user, the `twitch_id` value in the array is set to the database id, _not_ the actual twitch_id, so that's where something's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've set `protected $primaryKey` to a non-incremental value (`twitch_id`), I had to add `public $incrementing = false` to my `User` model, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40354360/2466375) post.